# Null pointer exception when trying to read har file

Tags: java, file, har

I am trying to read a har file and the `readHarFile` is throwing a null pointer exception. here is the sample code that i am trying to use:

```
public class readhar{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws exception{
    File f = new File ("file path");
    HarFileReader r = new HarFileReader();
    HarLog log = r.readHarFile(f);
    System.out.println(log);
  }
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
edu.umass.cs.benchlab.har.HarLog.<init>(HarLog.java:134) at 
edu.umass.cs.benchlab.har.tools.HarFileReader.readHarFile(HarFileReader.java:116‌​) at 
edu.umass.cs.benchlab.har.tools.HarFileReader.readHarFile(HarFileReader.java:89) at 
readHar.main(readHar.java:18) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native  Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav‌​a:43)
```

Comment: Does it compile? Does not look so. And could you also put the stack trace?

Comment: compilation didn't throw any errors.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at edu.umass.cs.benchlab.har.HarLog.<init>(HarLog.java:134)
 at edu.umass.cs.benchlab.har.tools.HarFileReader.readHarFile(HarFileReader.java:116)
 at edu.umass.cs.benchlab.har.tools.HarFileReader.readHarFile(HarFileReader.java:89)
 at readHar.main(readHar.java:18)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: did you check that the file you're trying to read actually exists? try adding `System.out.println("exists" + f.exists());` after instantating the new file.

Comment: its returning true. also i checked manually in the path and the file exists.

Comment: Fixed that issue by adding harlib-jackson-1.1final.jar